# Errors when compiling Orbotix HelloWorld

Tags: ios, sphero-api

While I've followed the release instructions for 1.6 b1146 to the letter, I'm still unable to get Orbotix' "HelloWorld" to compile.  I'm getting a lot of "Apple Mach-O Linker Error" messages.  What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:  Hmmm. Looks like Build | Mach-O Type should be set to "Static Library".  All but one of my error messages went away.

Those macho types get me every time. ;-0

UPDATE 11/18/13:

OK, when using Mach-O type "Static Library" setting, there is one remaining error message:

Command /Applications/Xcode 5.0.2.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool failed with exit code 1

How can I fix this?

UPDATE LATER 11/18/13:

I see in the release notes for 1.6b1146 a couple of sentences that read:  "The QuickStart App Template has been removed from this release since XCode 5 is not compatible.  Please use the following information to manually set up your project."

I've opened the Orbotix "HelloWorld" project and followed the instructions in the release notes, but I am still getting multiple Mach-0 errors.  I am running it on my iPhone 5s, not the emulator.

Do the quoted sentences above mean that none of the Orbotix sample code in the /trunk/samples directory will work?  Do I need to make my own HelloWorld project somehow by copying and pasting from the Orbotix sample code?

Comment: You'd be well served to ask a specific, answerable question - by providing the actual error messages, details on what steps caused them, and what you've tried so far to fix it.

Comment: Thanks for the nudge in the right direction (specific and answerable), Carl.  However, this is where Orbotix sends devs using their Sphero product, which seems to come with its share of arcane documentation.  So I'm hoping an Orbotix guy will come along and set me straight.  Stay tuned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phoebe - I just validated that the Sphero iOS SDK v1.6 Hello World sample compiles and executes on a 5s, 5, and 4s with no changes after downloading the Zip from **https://github.com/orbotix/Sphero-iOS-SDK**

Please validate that you are using a clean copy of the Hello World sample.

Comment: Great, this worked!  So the trick is to IGNORE THE RELEASE NOTES COMPLETELY to get the sample code up and running, and also not to use an emulator but instead your actual iOS device to run it on.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Phoebe719, I received word of your problems with the SDK through our customer service department. I'm sorry it took us a while for us to get back to you.

As for your issue, do you happen to be attempting to compile this onto an emulator? I myself have been baffled about the Mach-O linker errors when Xcode decides to not build to a device.

If you are building to an emulator, then I'm sorry, but there is no symbols in the iOS SDK for a mac to connect to a Sphero, and therefore, it just won't work. There is a mac SDK out there, but it is in a beta phase.

If not, then go ahead and leave a comment, and I'll see if we can't further diagnose the issue.